# What does "among other houses" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What does "among other houses" mean in

> "A burglar broke into my house, **among other houses**?"

Does it mean that a burglar picked out my house of all the houses or that a burglar broke into some houses including mine?

Comment: Is it your own sentence, or did you read it somewhere?

Comment: @SorryI'mDumb That's not the case. The normal meaning is that the burglar broke into the speaker's house and several others, not necessarily in the same area. The word "among" in this sense is not used in relation to physical location or proximity but in relation to a common characteristic, in this case that they had all been broken into by the same burglar.

Comment: It would be more usual just to say 'among others' (meaning 'and other houses as well').

Answer (score 1):

I think it means that the burglar broke into other houses as well.
I am not a native speaker, but I think the comma in the sentence is unnecessary.